# How to add an element to parent window? - Chrome Specific (All other browsers work)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, window.parent

So pretty much I have an html that has an iFrame.

```
<iframe src="frame.html" width="2000" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Now, from within the iFrame js I try to call jQuery's append function to add a DIV to the parent window...

```
$("body", window.parent.document).append("<div id=\"test\" ></div>");
```

That code works perfectly fine under FireFox and IE, but for some reason it doesn't work under Chrome, and I've tried Googling the cause of this with little to no luck.

*Just FYI, this was all done under jQuery 2.0.0.*

Comment: Works for me (in Chrome 26.0.1410.63): http://jsbin.com/ikumex/1/edit (iframe source: http://jsbin.com/ovasez/1/edit). (I reduced the size of the iframe by a factor of 10, but that's just to make it easier to see; it worked before I did that.)

Comment: It may be a cross origin problem. I'm currently developing on my own computer, therefore I'm accessing each iframe by providing a path. I think by putting the code live will fix this problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Okay so I just downloaded your code, then ran in in my own chrome then it the "Testing" will display ""inside"" the iframe window itself rather than it's parent's window.

Comment: (My Chrome version: 26.0.1410.64 m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently developing on my own computer, therefore I'm accessing each iframe by providing a path.

That's the problem. Use a local webserver and test via `http://` (or `https://`) URLs. If you test things you intend as web pages later via `file://` URLs, you will get misled.

In this case, your suspicion in your comment is right: It's the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Different browsers treat origin `null` (the local file system) differently. Chrome disallows access to other windows when your window is loaded from a local file.